# Multiple params in ActionLink not rendering as needed in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view that has multiple partial views on it. It is a settings page. They can click a site on the left panel, ad it will display all the settings for managing that site in the partial view on the page. When I build the links of the sites, I use the following Razor code as an example:

```
        List<Site> siteList = Site.GetSites(new SiteQuery());
        foreach (Site site in siteList)
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(@site.Name, "SelectSite", "SettingsController", new { id = Model.EnvironmentID, siteId = @site.SiteID}, null)</li>
        }
```

And here is the ActionResult I am trying to hit in the SetitngsController controller:

```
        public ActionResult SelectSite(int id, int siteId)
        {    
            //..code here
        }
```

The error occurs thhough, because my URL it outputs is as follows:

~/SettingsController/SelectSite/1?siteId=1

instead of being ~/SettingsController/SelectSite/?id=1&siteId=1344

Am I obvioulsy misunderstanding how to be able to update the current view on the page with a new url and adding params to it this way. Is this wrong in MVC theory, or am I just missing somthing?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks. Sorry been up all night and exhausted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of your routing table. By default it looks like `{Controller}\{Action}\{id}`, so your id param is right after action.

You can either change param name or change routing (but the last solution has much more complexity), for example:

```
@Html.ActionLink(site.Name, 
                 "SelectSite", 
                 "SettingsController", 
                 new { environmentID = Model.EnvironmentID, siteId = site.SiteID}, null)

public ActionResult SelectSite(int environmentID, int siteId)
    {    
        //..code here
    }
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. I am liking MVC so far, but is different to get use to. I just started a few days ago. Anyways, thanks again.